# elasticsearch cloud - access config/elasticsearch.yml file

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `elasticsearch cloud` service and need to update the `elasticsearch.yml` config file to update the search configuration to include:

`indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`

`elasticsearch cloud` is hosting the nodes on `aws`

Is there a way to access this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to access this remotely. Cloud service requires a request to [elasticsearch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-set-indices-query-bool-max-clause-count/62734/2) itself.